# How to close Xcode without confirmation when a task is a running

Tags: xcode

I have to restart Xcode frequently because of bugs in Interface Builder.

It's quite annoying that I have to confirm close whenever I have my app running inside a simulator or device:

[image]

Is there a way (setting, or plugin?) to disable this pop-up and automatically stop all tasks when I exit Xcode?